# Apache2 "пожирает память" при long poll запросах

Tags: apache2

Апач поедает память процессами при long poll запросах.
Используется технология long poll, как в данном видео:
http://www.screenr.com/SNH

Из-за цикла проверки времени при многократном обновлении страницы происходит плодение процессов апача и забивка памяти, поскольку maxClients на апаче стоит 256, то апач, перейдя границу - зависает. Помогает только перезапуск.
На апаче стоит itk модуль.
Php подключен как модуль апача.

Comment: . long po**l**l

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте [Nginx](http://nginx.org/ru/) как прокси и еще лучше к нему поставить [php-fpm](http://php-fpm.org) вместо апача. Иначе `maxClients` надо ставить очень и очень большим, что в итоге все равно приведет к паденю апача при нагрузках.

`Nginx` хорошо работает с медленными клиентами и отлично справляется с нагрузками. В связке с апачем он его разгрузит. А в связке с `php-fpm` вы вообще забудете о головной боли ;)

### UPD

А еще лучше на [Веб-сокеты](https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets) перейти. Скорость работы вырастет, а нагрузка упадет.